# Why Are Perpetual Motion Machines Defined As Not Having An External Energy Source?

Tags: energy-conservation, definition, perpetual-motion

Perpetual motion means motion that continues indefinitely if interpreted just by the meaning of the words. So why is the concept connected to having no energy source? Its not no-energy motion, its only perpetual. Even if it is supplied of energy from an external source, as long as it does continue infinitely, it is indeed perpetual motion.

However it seems that at least the popular description involves in no energy input or no additional energy input. Take a look at the following articles

https://www.britannica.com/science/perpetual-motion

".....with no additional energy required to maintain it." -excerpt from the article

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion#:~:text=A%20perpetual%20motion%20machine%20of,law%20of%20conservation%20of%20energy.&text=This%20conversion%20of%20heat%20into,the%20second%20law%20of%20thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_motion#:%7E:text=A%20perpetual%20motion%20machine%20of,law%20of%20conservation%20of%20energy.&text=This%20conversion%20of%20heat%20into,the%20second%20law%20of%20thermodynamics).

"....A perpetual motion machine is a hypothetical machine that can do work infinitely without an external energy source. " -excerpt from the article

But perpetual motion machines could have external energy sources that constantly resupply the energy needed. For example, take an object with mass. Place a container shaped like so(the part labeled A with the slope is connected to the walls of this device that are removed so you can view the interior)

[image]

If the unoccupied space in this container was filled with an appropriate amount of water or other liquids, some will overflow over the slope and move downwards, this motion of water would be perpetual as long as the whole planet-container system is unperturbed. This isn't free energy generation or no-energy motion, its just a physically valid cause and effect by spacetime curvature and how objects with positive mass are effected by it.

This is perpetual motion, but, this isn't no-energy motion.

Comment: Things get names because people want to talk about them. A machine that would run forever, producing useful energy would be... useful. People fantasize about having one, and they talk about their fantasies, and they call it "perpetual motion." The closest thing to literal perpetual motion in our immediate neighborhood probably is the planets which have been orbiting the Sun for the last several billion years without any new energy being added. But for some reason, that doesn't inspire as much conversation as the idea of a "free energy" "perpetual motion" machine.

Comment: Okay. Do you think this answers the question of why some people equate "perpetual motion" with "no energy motion"? I think not.

Answer (score 3):

Perpetual motion machines are hypothetical ideas, whereby a system would do work without any external input. If you constantly supply more energy, then that's not a perpetual motion machine, because if you stop supplying energy, the motion doesn't perpetuate. Arguing against that is like saying "I keep filling the fuel tank on my car, and it keeps going. Is that perpetual motion?"

Your idea is interesting, yet flawed. Why would the water keep flowing down the slope? How does the water counteract the effect of gravity to get back to the top of the slope? You'd need a constant input of energy to get the water up above the top of the slope to get it back down again. Bear in mind that even in an ideal system where no turbulence occurs in the fluid, you'd still have a frictional force between the flowing water and surface of the slope and the walls.

Comment: If there was just enough water so they flow over the slope, but all enter the container again, the amount of water never changes. But they were overflowing before and the amount never changed, so they are still overflowing. And when they flow out of the higher point, the gravitational pull makes them flow down the slope. Yes, they could flow out of the container if there were too much, but by extending the roof on the lower exit, and changing the slope they can be made to all refill the container.

Comment: I think I'm missing something. How do you make the water flow straight up continuously, without adding extra energy? Yes, the flow down may push some water underneath and exert a force upwards, but the energy lost to turbulence, friction would overcome that. This is something that can be imagined another way: if you send a toy car on a loop-the-loop, it eventually stops moving around. Add more cars and you get the same result. That's what's happening here, but with water molecules instead of toy cars.

Comment: Because their amount stays the same, and the volume doesn't change nor does the container, some of the water has to overflow. As it did in the beginning. Is there a reason water should somehow crumple up at the low end? If there isn't at least some water would have to flow out because there simply isn't enough volume.

Comment: @Upsilon17 Water column in the right will produce greater pressure than on the left. So newly added fluid will have less resistance to simply overflow through the left lower edge of container than to crawl up in the right side for no reason. Will not work.

Comment: @Upsilon17 Pressure in the right side will come to equilibrium to pressure in the left side and motion will stop.